# How do I check the deploy status of Github Pages? (Specifically: Project Pages w/ Jekyll)

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a working Github Page. *(Specifically: a Project Page with Jekyll that lives at `[username].github.io/[project_name]/`.)*

I can deploy. *(By pushing changes to my `gh-pages` branch and waiting a few minutes for it to build.)*

**How can I check the deploy/build status?**

It's annoying to wait an unknown number of minutes after I push my changes to Github. I searched for 20 minutes and was surprised to find nothing. Am I misunderstanding something or using the wrong terms? o.O

Comment: Obviously you can look at the URL where it lives yourself, so what exactly are you wanting? A notification?

Comment: Honestly? A progress bar :D But a status message would be cool too (it's 'building' still? great, it's not broken). And if that's too much to ask for, a notification would be waaay better than nothing.

Answer (score 27):

The easiest thing to do is to go to the commits page for your repo (`https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/commits/master`) and there will be a green check mark when it's done building. For example:

[image]

You can also query the Github API. For example using curl:

```
$ curl -u USERNAME https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPO/pages/builds/latest

{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPO/pages/builds/12345678",
  "status": "built",
  ...
"created_at": "2018-07-26T17:23:42Z"
```

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/pages/#get-latest-pages-build

Some example statuses you might see:

- `queued`
- `building`
- `built`
- `error`

Comment: Thanks! That green check is what I needed to find.

Answer (score 11):

A simple solution is to add a time-stamp somewhere in your site.

For example, I added a time-stamp in my <del>about</del> page (**EDIT again**: I have put time-stamp inside my [rss.xml](http://yizeng.me/rss.xml) now). Then I'd know if the site has been deployed or not.

Inside my rss.xml, I have:

```
<lastBuildDate>{{ site.time | date_to_rfc822 }}</lastBuildDate>
```

It gives time-stamp after deploying:

```
<lastBuildDate>Tue, 29 Apr 2014 21:07:52 +1200</lastBuildDate>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good idea. I'm not accepting it as the final answer (yet) because I'm still holding out hope that there's a more "supported" solution.

Comment: @thewillcole well ? it's been some years now :)

Answer (score 6):

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. On the right side, you will find Environments and Github Pages.
3. Click on GitHub pages to see the deployment status

Reference Link : https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/viewing-deployment-activity-for-your-repository

Answer (score 0):

It's on the right side of the repository page.
[image]

Or at https://github.com/**USER**/**REPO**/deployments